# Predicate logic: Definition of prime numbers

Tags: predicate-logic

I have come up with this definition: n is prime iff

$$(n>1)\ \wedge \ \left[ \forall x.\ \  (\exists k. n=kx) \implies (x=1 \vee x=n) \right]
$$

Is this definition correct?

Comment: Yes .. assuming your domain is the natural numbers

Comment: Yes it is. I should put it in there

Comment: Fun historical fact:  The old definition of prime was just the right conjunct. That is, 1 used to be a prime. Put differently: under the old definition, a prime number was one with *at most* two divisors. Now, it is a number with *exactly* two divisors. Which itself you can formalize as: $\forall n (Prime(n) \leftrightarrow \exists x \exists y  (x \not = y \land  \forall z (\exists k \ n = kz \leftrightarrow (z = x \lor z = y))))$